# Programmatically access Jenkins URL?

Tags: java, url, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I programmatically access Jenkins URL field that is configured through Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins Location?

I tried `Computer.currentComputer().getUrl()` but returns only `computer/(master)/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the way I use to do it:

```
JenkinsLocationConfiguration globalConfig = new JenkinsLocationConfiguration();
globalConfig.getUrl()
```

Comment: Thanx Estaban once again ;)

Comment: @peter_budo - Did you able to access the Jenkins URL from java code.I was working on this and unable to access Jenkins URL from java code. Thanks.

Comment: @user222 yes I did, hence why I market question as solved. However as you can see it was 4 years ago. Since then things may have changed... I would suggest you to have look on the documentation for writing your own Jenkins plugin, that did helped me a lot. Plus many plugins have repo that you can clone and poke around code see what other people did

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [JenkinsLocationConfiguration class](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/JenkinsLocationConfiguration.html) of the other answer, [Jenkins.getInstance.getRootUrl()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getRootUrl%28%29) returns the configured url.

Also check [Jenkins.getInstance.getRootUrlFromRequest()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getRootUrlFromRequest%28%29), it returns the real url in use, but only while processing a request.

Comment: @hyde-I want to access Jenkins URL from java code, its throwing me 403 exception. I have seen the link you shared http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#getRootUrl%28%29. Do i need to download any jar file to use this API. Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: @user222 Your question makes no sense to me, sorry. How would adding JARs to your project help solve 403 http error? Anyway, haven't coded in Java for almost 4 years, so don't remember any details. Check javadocs, and try the URL on browser, use debgugger/debug prints to check what causes the exception, etc normal troubleshooting.

Comment: @hyde - Thanks for the response, I was talking about the jar files for the class JenkinsLocationConfiguration mentioned in the post, and yes I'm trying all possible ways to debug and find the issue. I'm trying to hit the Jenkins URL from my java code which is throwing me the exception. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @user222 Sounds like you are not writing Jenkins plugin? In that case this answer is not relevant to you in any way. These classes are part of Jenkins framework.